# Replay part of the history?

Tags: sonarqube

### Context

Our build/analysis job wrongly disabled and then reenabled a quality profile causing a whole bunch of old issues to be tagged as new and so appearing in the leak period.

### Question

What would be the best way to correct this ?

I first thought I could replay part of the history deleting the analysis which were causing the issue and then use the sonar.projectDate to fill the blank.
But SonarQube doesn't allow to delete the latest analysis !

Is there another way ? or do I need to delete the project and start all over again ?

thanks for any advice

Comment: The influence of quality profiles for some special cases has been changed in 6.3. Which version do you use?

Comment: I'm now using the 6.3, but the problematic analysis were done with 5.6